# Game of Life: find neighbours

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I'm making a Life game and I made this method to find nearby neighbours

```
private int getNeighbours(LifeBoard board, int row, int col){
    if(board.get(row+1, col)){
        neighbours++;
    }
    if(board.get(row-1, col)){
        neighbours++;
    }
    if(board.get(row, col+1)){
        neighbours++;
    }
    if(board.get(row, col-1)){
        neighbours++;
    }
    if(board.get(row+1, col+1)){
        neighbours++;
    }
    if(board.get(row-1, col-1)){
        neighbours++;
    }
    if(board.get(row+1, col-1)){
        neighbours++;
    }
    if(board.get(row-1, col+1)){
        neighbours++;
    }

    return neighbours;
}
```

I feel as if it's horribly coded and cringe at it, therefore my question is.. Is there a way to make this better? Right now, it "sort-of" works but I'm thinking if I could do this with a loop instead.

Thanks.

Comment: Better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jon Skeet has the right answer. However if you start having a big field your original way will execute faster because you basically unrolled the loop and loop unrolling is always faster than a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can use loops and just explicitly exclude the location itself (i.e. when the x and y offset are both 0):

```
private int getNeighbours(LifeBoard board, int row, int col) {
    int neighbours = 0;
    for (int xOffset = -1; xOffset < 2; xOffset++) {
        for (int yOffset = -1; yOffset < 2; yOffset++) {
            if ((xOffset != 0 || yOffset != 0)
                  && board.get(row + yOffset, col + xOffset)) {
                neighbours++;
            }
        }
    }
    return neighbours;
}
```

This assumes your `board.get(...)` method is okay with values off the edge of the board.

Alternative strategies for the offsets:

- As above, `for (int xOffset = -1; xOffset < 2; xOffset++)`
- Use an inclusive upper bound: `for (int xOffset = -1; xOffset <= 1; xOffset++)`
- Use an array defined elsewhere:

  ```
  private static final int[] OFFSETS = { -1, 0, 1 };
  ...
  for (int xOffset : OFFSETS)
  ```

Comment: I would use something like `OFFSETS = new int[] {-1, 0, 1}` and `for (int xOffset : OFFSETS) {...}`

Comment: @njzk2: That would do it as well, yes.